# how to clear cache memory when the application exits by programatically

Tags: android

friend's,
 I have set of images fetched from internet and set it on gridview,here i have option to click here to view more,below the grid view and it fetches images and set it on grid with prevoius set of images,when i exit the application and run it again,the previous set of images remain in cache and grid shows images from cache,here i need to clear my application cache memory,when i exited my application.how can i get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you defining "exit the application and run it again"? How are you defining "remain in cache"?

Comment: while clicking device back button and also from UI....

Comment: Where do you save the fetched data? In your app's data folder?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't exit the app (using BACK button) but pressed HOME button instead.